# How fix local language text encoding problems of winform controls

Tags: c#, winforms, encoding, designer, vs-community-edition

In windowsForm Designer, I placed a label on form. Wrote some Turkish characters for its text property. `text > "Giriş"` which means login.

When application is started, `ş` char is not displayed correct. Some kind of encoding problem

Windows10 has 2 language packs > English (US) and Turkish. English is default and current language used. I do not want to change text of design elements programmatically. I want to use the FormDesigner.

Here is what i see in Windows Form Designer

[image]

And here is what i see when running

[image]

Comment: When you open the designer does the `Text` of label show correctly?

Comment: Text is showing fine in FormDesigner. Not when app started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set both the `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` as per [Microsoft's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b28bx3bh(VS.80).aspx) example:

```
// C#
// Put the using statements at the beginning of the code module
using System.Threading;  
using System.Globalization;

// Put the following code before InitializeComponent()
// Sets the culture to French (France)
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");

// Sets the UI culture to French (France)
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
```

You can set this once at application start-up.